# Tocar som de alerta após consulta no banco (PHP + MYSQL)

Tags: php, javascript, html5, html5-audio

Preciso que seja tocado um som de alerta após uma consulta no banco...

**Exemplo lógico:**

NUM_LINHAS = NUMERO DE LINHAS DA TABELA

SE (NUM_LINHAS > 0){
    *play();*
}

**Minha função javaScript que toca o som:**

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">

    audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play(){
    audio.play();
}

</script>
```

> A função "play()" está funcionando pois criei um botão para testar e o
>   som é reproduzido através do onclick()

```
<input type="button" value="test sound" onclick="play()";>
```

OK. Agora preciso que este som de alerta seja tocado após a minha consulta no banco, que terá uma condição.

**Segue o código:**

```
<?php                           
//seleciona o numero de linhas da tabela
$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toyota_base where statuz='NOVO'");                            

//atribui a variavel $num_rows o numero de linhas
$num_rows = $consulta->fetchColumn();

//verifica se o numero de linhas é maior que 0 (zero)                       
if($num_rows > 0){
    //toca o som de alerta
    echo "<script> play();</script>";
}

?>
```

Não sei porque mais o som não é tocado...preciso de ajuda com isso.
Fiz um teste com um "alert()" ao invez de minha função "play()" e o alert funciona corretamente, mas o som não toca...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua função javascript provavelmente não estava funcionando (acredito que) porque você estava "tocando" o som antes do elemento `audio` ser criado. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
//seleciona o numero de linhas da tabela
$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toyota_base where statuz='NOVO'");

//atribui a variavel $num_rows o numero de linhas
$num_rows = $consulta->fetchColumn();

//verifica se o numero de linhas é maior que 0 (zero)
if($num_rows > 0){
    //toca o som de alerta
    echo "<script> play();</script>"; // <-- O elemento audio só vai ser criado daqui algumas linhas,
                                      //     não tem como ele ser tocado ainda.
}

?>

<audio id="audio">
   <source src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">

   audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play(){
   audio.play();
}

</script>
```

Se você estiver usando jQuery troque seu `echo` por:

```
echo "<script> jQuery(document).ready(play);</script>";
```

Se não estiver, [aqui tem uma pergunta (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the) sobre
como criar o evento `ready` com javascript puro.

Ou simplesmente coloque o `if` e no elemento `audio`:

```
<?php 
    if($num_rows > 0){
?>
<audio id="audio" autoplay>
   <source src="alert.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Assim o elemento `audio` só será criado se houver registros na tabela e não gerará consumo de banda desnecessária baixando o áudio quando não houver (o mesmo acontece com sua solução `embed`). Note também que o atributo `autoplay` faz com que o audio seja reproduzido automaticamente quando estiver pronto e não precisa criar nenhuma função javascript pra isso.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a resposta:

Ao invés de usara minha função javascript, usei somente a linha:

```
<embed src='alert.mp3'width='1' height='1'>
```

E isso resolveu o problema.

**Código final:**

```
<?php  

//seleciona o numero de linhas da tabela
$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM toyota_base where statuz='NOVO'");                            

//atribui a variavel $num_rows o numero de linhas
$num_rows = $consulta->fetchColumn();

//verifica se o numero de linhas é maior que 0 (zero)                       
if($num_rows > 0){
    //toca o som de alerta
    echo "<embed src='alert.mp3'width='1' height='1'>";
}

?>
```

É isso, pra quem precisar algum dia, a solução está aí.